# SharePoint development nightmares

Tags: sharepoint

I thought I'd give SharePoint development a go, to broaden my understanding of Microsoft technologies and ran into a situation I refuse to understand.

I have a new web application created: http://localhost:11523 and set up the site collection as required. I can browse to the web site fine, without any issues, but now I want to start developing against this, using the object model.

Right, so after I struggled with `SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost:11523");` I figured that I'm not running VS2008 in elevated permissions, so restarting VS I finally got one step further.

Whenever I step into my code, I get:

> The Web application at
>   http://localhost:11523/ could not be
>   found.

I've Googled this without luck. The application is most definitely there, I can browse it, add web parts and go mad. I just can't seem to connect to it via Visual Studio.

Any ideas would be great.

> EDIT

I thought I'd isolate my method, called "GetListFromSharePoint(string name)" into a test method (nUnit Framework) and to my surprise returned 9 entries from the list, as expected. When I dumped the method back into my web application (not SharePoint, trying to test the Composite Control through a normal Web site), and run into the mentioned problem.

This is in SharePoint 2007, and I'm developing on the same machine onto which SharePoint 2007 is installed.

This approach used to work, for some reason, I just can't get it to recognize SharePoint. The test stubs work find, just not the web application.

> Edit 2

So there where a couple of things I "missed", which kind of solved the problem by itself.

Firstly, I was developing on a x64 Windows 2008 box, thus SharePoint 2007 was running in x64 mode. Cassini, turns out, is 32bit regardless of the platform you run it on, which caused some compiler bugs (I did not have IA64 compilers installed). After installing this, I figured out that the default web site (localhost:80) had been disabled by SharePoint.

Renabling the default web site, allowed me to create my web application as a virtual directory against it, which allowed my debugger compiler to run in x64.

My next challenge was access permissions. Because any new virtual directory on port 80 is assigned to the default application pool, is it assumed that the user does not have the right permissions, so I had to change my web application to run under my SharePoint web application's application pool.

The last thing I had to do was run my SharePoint code with elevated permissions.

Working like a charm :D

Note! Enable debug on your SharePoint web application....

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Check the event viewer. I'm thinking you may have some database login errors in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(You have not specified version - assuming SharePoint 2010).

You need to decide what object model you want to use:

- client (to be able to access the server from any other machine)
- server (the one that you are trying now, can only be run locally).

Most likley reasons your code not work:

- using "localhost" instead of ""computer name" in the Url. (I believe it is the reason.)
- you are running your code not on the same machine as the SharePoint
- you are running code under non-admin account

Check out how sites collections are configured in "Central Administration" site - urls associated with each site collection are listed there - make sure you are using correct one.

You can also try enumerating all site collections in SPWebApplication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.sites.aspx) to start expiriments.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the SPSite connect through the IIS, and if SharePoint isn't set up to respond to localhost (done in the Central Administration) you wont be able to connect to that url. IIS works a bit different here since it relays the signals to "localhost" to the "web application instance".

Start by checking in your SharePoint Central Administration. Go to "Configure alternate access mappings" in the "System Settings" section. Here you have your SharePoint instances, there are three properties which you can see directly in the list; 'Internal URL', 'Zone' and 'Public URL for Zone'.

If the Internal URL isn't set to Localhost you wont be able to use that connection you suggested. It bay be improper to change this to another url as well, so simply try to set your  SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yourinternalurl:11523"); to whatever's in that box! :)

Cheers